# How to wake up a process by PID? (in C)

Tags: c, mutex, wait, semaphore, pid

I have a shared memory X (array), 2 type of process and I have 3 semaphores, one for modifier X and the other one is for wait until I want to wake up one of these waited process.

Step by step:

```
1. I'm the process 1 and I ask for semaphore 1 (mutex).
2. OK I got it so I can add me in the array, now I wait (semaphore 2).
3. REPITE this for all the process
```

Now I have an array with 20 PID's for example, and I want wake up the process 5 (x[4]).

The question is: how can I wake up this process? How can I send a signal to a concret PID?

Excuse my english...

Thank you guys!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use the [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) syscall to send a signal to some given process.

I am not sure it is the best way to synchronize (I believe it is not; read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)). You could use Posix semaphores [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) (or even old SysV semaphores [svipc(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/svipc.7.html))  or pipes [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) (or [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) sockets) with [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)